# Is there a better way to update the height and width of an image with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to update the image height and width after dynamically loading a new thumb.  I'm currently doing it like so:

```
...
$('#thumb_' + newID).attr('width', 120);
$('#thumb_' + newID).attr('height', 120);
$('#thumb_' + newID).attr('src', data.thumb + '?v=' + ( new Date() ).getTime());
```

It seems like the height and width are always getting set but the image doesn't always fit the dimensions specified.

Is there a better more reliable way to do this?

Comment: Why not specify it in CSS instead?

Comment: Why not check the size of where they have to fit with the .height() and .width() functions, and calculate the size adhoc for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this; with the css function instead of the attr function after changing the source

```
var newsource=data.thumb + '?v=' + ( new Date() ).getTime();
$('#thumb_' + newID).attr('src', newsource).css({height : 120, width : 120});
```